# How do some API services accept Authorization headers from all origins?

Tags: javascript, express, http, cors, http-headers

Stripe/Square/etc allow you to put your API key in an `Authorization` header as a `Bearer` token. However, from what I understand, you can't allow credentials (which includes the `Authorization` header) from all origins. So how are they accepting requests with that header from all origins?

Answer (score 0):

I think they just set

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

from their server

Comment: Yes, but the issue is you can't allow `*` and credentials at the same time. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSNotSupportingCredentials

Comment: They just dont use credentials and Authorization header at the same time. Client only can use 1 way to authen

Comment: Thanks, I assumed that it was scrubbing the Authorization header or something if I didn't allow credentials, but I was incorrect. It ended up being some other issue.